# Implementing performFetchWithCompletionHandler delegate in a custom iOS framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, ios-frameworks

I am developing a custom framework for connectivity related services and I would need to implement the ***performFetchWithCompletionHandler*** delegate inside my framework. ( Will require to do some data fetch/download ) when the app is in the background.

Since a framework is not an application, hence am not able to see the **capabilities** section under project target.
And since the host application who will be using the framework, won't have any idea what I will be required to download, is there a way to implement this functionality inside the framework ?

I tried making a class conform to the UIApplicationDelegate protocol and implemented the performFetchWithCompletionHandler protocol inside it, but the method does not get hit when I simulate a background fetch. Only the application's performFetchWithCompletionHandler always get hit.